# Prove $2^n > n$ and $2^{n+1}>n!$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, induction, graphing-functions

Prove $2^n > n$ and if $2^{n+1}>n!$.

I am currently studying noetherian rings and found (quite embarrassingly) that I have forgotten basic proofs as such. I want to know if my proofs are airtight.

For $2^n >n$, I use induction. Base case is obvious, and I assume for $n$ and prove for $n+1$. We prove $2^{n+1} = 2 \cdot 2^{n}$ and since $2^n > n $ then $2 \cdot 2^n > 2n = n+n > n+1$.

I feel there was an unnecessary step. For the second proof, base case is also obvious. I assume for $n-1$ and prove for $n$. Thus,
$2^{n-1}>(n-1)!$ which implies $2^n > 2(n-1)!$ but this is wrong because $2(n-1)! \not\ge n!$. I then show that $x!$ eventually overtakes $2^{x+1}$ at almost $x = 4.33...$ but I got curious and would like to find an exact algebraic formula where $2^{x+1}=x!$. I know there are multiple points where they intersect, especially behind $x=0$, but how would I find these solutions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's no formulas to solve that kind of equations, but using numeric methods you can find the solutions to any precision required.

Comment: @jjagmath Is there a proof that there exists no algebraic solution? Please send the link if there is

Comment: @fiftytwo, you should write $2^{\color{red}{\mathbf n}}>(n-1)!$ instead of $2^{n-1}>(n-1)!\;$.

Comment: A counter example is sufficient: 
$2^{11}\ \large{\not >} \normalsize \   10!$

Comment: @Angelo Yes, another counter example.

Comment: @callculus42, also $2^6\not>5!$ and it is the smallest counterexample in $\Bbb N$.

Comment: @Angelo It is not necessary for the counter example to be the smallest.

Comment: Your question is not really focused. There is nothing related to noetherian rings, and the two inequalties and their proofs are distinct problems from trying to find the solutions to $2^{x+1} = x!$. In any case Stirling's formula is relevant for the second inequality

Comment: @CalvinKhor Sorry I didn't phrase my question correctly. (By the way, Khor is such a cool name)